# CSS border-bottom problems

Tags: css

I want to have a border that separate the title and the text , I have it but is 100% of the h2 and I wanted to have it like 80% and in the center.

I tried to take separate the h2 but if I add a width of 80% it makes the h2 80% width of the entire div. PS I hope this code shows the way I wanted.

```
.about-section .title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px; 
  font-size: 20px;
}
.title h2 {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #fe9004;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Please provide us with me a simple html of your case

Comment: here you can see the codepen: https://codepen.io/raul-rogojan/pen/arqmoe?editors=0100

Comment: you might try Jan solution below, it works

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pseudo-element `:after` to achieve this:

```css
.about-section .title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px; 
  font-size: 20px;
}
.title h2 {
  position: relative;
}
.title h2:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 10%;
  background-color: #fe9004;
}
```

```html
<div class="about-section">
  <div class="title">
    <h2>About</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting , I tried this before but your code doesn't work as it pushes the line to the bottom and as I said width: 80% makes it 80% of the entire div . This is the code that kinda works for me but I can't center it nor add a margin-bottom to push the text down . Here you have the code pen https://codepen.io/raul-rogojan/pen/arqmoe?editors=1100

Comment: Fixed it ! position:absolute was the problem . I still cant add a margin-bottom but I'll figure that out

Comment: To get it the _line_ centered, you have to move 10% from left. `left: 10%;`. To push the content-div (text) further down you can add the margin to the `.title`-style.